# How to open a file with Python with white spaces in the name?

Tags: python

I have files that cannot be renamed without white spaces (work files). The file name is `Evo PROG6001  FSJD0250240  E.PART` stored in a variable `file`. If I run `os.system('start ' "'" + file + "'")` it only recognizes the word `Evo` and returns `Windows cannot find "Evo". Make sure you types the name correctly, and then try again`. The same thing occurs with `os.system('start ' + file)`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Build your command string in a variable of its own, and hand that string to the `os.system` call.  This gives you an opportunity to troubleshoot the actual string you're handing to the call.

Comment: Don't use `os.system`, use `subprocess.call(['start', filename], shell=True)` or even `subprocess.call(['cmd.exe', '/c', 'start', filename])`.

Comment: I've tried something similar, this just opens a cmd window with the correct working directory but no command is executed, it's just sitting there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use `os.startfile()` and also point it to the root directory, which I had stored previously.

`os.startfile(new_folder + '\\' + file)` works